# Error using rsDriver of the RSelenium package in R

Tags: r, rselenium

I am trying to open a browser using the RSelenium package in R.

When using this command

```
rs_driver_object <- rsDriver(browser="chrome", 
                             chromever = "113.0.5672.63",
                             verbose = F,
                             port=free_port())
```

I get this error

```
Error in gsub("\\s+", ",", ActiveConnections) : input string 1 is invalid
In addition: Warning message:
In gsub("\\s+", ",", ActiveConnections) :
  unable to translate '  Proto  Adresse locale         Adresse distante       <90>tat' to a wide string
```

Here are the first lines of my code, they work well

```
library(tidyverse)
library(RSelenium)
library(netstat)
library(wdman)

# To download chromedriver
selenium()

# To find where chromedriver is installed
selenium_object <- selenium (retcommand = T, check = F)

# Versions to use
binman::list_versions("chromedriver")
```

Here is my Google Chrome version : 113.0.5672.127

and here is the result of the line with binman :

```
$win32
 "113.0.5672.24" "113.0.5672.63" "114.0.5735.16"
```

So using the 113.0.5672.63 version of chromedriver should work.

I think the error comes from free_port() which allows me to find a free port. I have tried not to use but if I don't say which port I'm using or if I use a random port, it can tell me that the port is already in use and so it doesn't work. I would like something that works every time, so free_port() would be a good fit if it would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across the same problem. It isn't a problem in the `RSelenium` package, it's in the `netstat`.  I've typed `netstat –s –p tcp` in my command prompt and saw that the statistics were coming out in my local language. Until developers resolve this, you've to change your OS language to English.